# FullCalendar JS modify day Names in mobile

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, responsiveness

In desktop I want to have ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday',
 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'] days. And in mobile will change to ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'].

Answer (score 1):

You need to use mobile detect api for that and then you can set two different array for both of the device mobile and desktop.

Please Refer below link for mobile detect API :
http://mobiledetect.net/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Chetan for the reply. I've been using **windowResize** : https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/windowResize/ to detect mobile window sizes but my problem is how to insert "
**dayNamesShort" ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']** into the calendar.

Here's my code:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  windowResize: function(view) {
     if ($(window).width() < 768){
         // insert dayNamesShort:  ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'] without destorying current events
     }
  }


});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change [columnFormat](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/columnFormat/) when detect mobile window sizes:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'columnFormat', 'dd');
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qhzk7xsy/)